# HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE differs from navigator.language in Firefox in Linux

Tags: javascript, php, linux, firefox

I am programming some webpages in a local Apache 2 web server in Linux, and I would like to use PHP to auto-recognize the browser language.

In the webpage I am trying to `console.log()` with JavaScript about which language the client has as preferred and I get 2 different outputs:

- JavaScript (`console.log(navigator.language);`) returns `es-ES`
- PHP (`<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'] ?>`) returns `en-US,en;q=0.5`

In the `about:config`, the variable `intl.accept_languages` is set to `es-ES, es, en-US, en`.

NOTE: My local language, which I want to achive to get, is spanish (`es-ES`).

For any reason, Firefox seems to not be properly configured in my Linux distro (Linux Mint 18.1), while I have everything installed (`firefox` and `firefox-locale-es`).

If I try with Chromium in the same computer, the PHP output is `es-ES,es;q=0.8;q=0.6`, which is correct.

If I try with Firefox in other computer with Windows, or even with Firefox for Android, the PHP output is also correct: `es-ES,es;q=0.8;en-US,en;q=0.5`.

Why is the PHP output wrong in Firefox for Linux and how to solve it? Thanks in advance.

---

EDIT: These are the HTTP headers (I crossed out the authentication headers)

Request:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Referer: https://localhost/
Cookie: PHPSESSID=crucsit7is3r6hvnd88k6q2rn5
Authorization: ########
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 25 Jul 2017 20:39:21 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Authentication-Info: ########
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 1301
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Comment: What is actually being posted in the HTTP headers?

Comment: @Pointy Sorry, I don't understand your question. What do you want me to check?

Comment: Use the browser developer tools to see what the actual HTTP request (and response) headers are.

Comment: @Pointy All right, I have posted the headers in the question

Comment: When I set my Linux Firefox up so that I have Spanish/Spain as my most preferred language, I definitely get an `Accept-Languages` header that includes Spanish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found a solution while i was trying to sleep, just because Chrome did something like years ago.

> Thanks to @Pointy for trying to help anyway

So if someone also have this problem, this are the steps:

1. Enter in the configuration panel in Firefox (`about:config` in the search bar).
2. Search for the `intl.accept_languages` variable.
3. Replace whatever you have as your default value with a different language in this format: `xx-Xx, xx`, for example `de-DE, de`. The most important part is that this variable has to change its state from "default" to a "user-modified" one.
4. Replace again its value with the correct value: your own values + the default Firefox values, which are `es-ES, es, en-US, en` (Replace the `es-ES, es` part with your values, for example, `fr-FR, fr, en-US, en`).
5. The HTTP headers should have been reset with this configuration.